# Is there some simple way to apply image preprocess to tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I wonder the efficient way to apply image preprocess(e.g. rotation, hrizontal flip, padding, crop, etc...) to data made by tf.data API

My data is made like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

// train_data -> numpy array, (50000, 32, 32, 3)
// test_data -> numpy array, (10000, 32, 32, 3)

train_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_labels)).shuffle(50000).batch(128)
test_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_data, test_labels)).batch(128)
```

So is there good way to apply some preprocess to my dataset ?

I know ImageDataGenerator in Keras API is so simple way, but I want to know how image can be processed in tf.data API too.

Comment: Have you looked at the `tf.dataset.map()` and `tf.dataset.apply()` functions (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)? You can use those along with `tf.image` functions to achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: @thushv89 It seems like good to me. I will see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can apply these kind of transformations:

```
def parse_data_train(image, label):
    # Function that we will use to parse the training data
    image = tf.image.random_crop(image, [WIDTH, HEIGHT, NUM_CHANNELS])
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)

    return image, label

def parse_data_val_test(image, label):
    # Function that we will use to parse the validation/test data
    image = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(image, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    return image, label


WIDTH, HEIGHT, NUM_CHANNELS = 10, 10, 3
train_data = np.random.rand(100, 32, 32, 3)
train_labels = np.random.rand(100, 10)
test_data = np.random.rand(10, 32, 32, 3)
test_labels = np.random.rand(10, 10)

# Creating the training dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_labels))
# Shuffle of the dataset upon creation and shuffle it after each epoch
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=train_data.shape[0], reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
# Apply the transformations on the dataset
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_data_train)
# Create the batches
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(10)

# Create the test dataset
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_data, test_labels))
# No need to shuffle since we just validate/test on this dataset
# Apply the transformations for the validation/test dataset
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(parse_data_val_test)
# Create the batches
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(10)
```

To summarize, I would suggest to rely on `tf.data.Dataset.map()` because you can easily create your own methods where you can stack the transformations yo want to apply on each sample of the dataset.